# Browser console.log and code console.log showing different

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, web-development-server

I was creating a carousel.
I don't know what the hell is going on anymore,
in my
HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Carousel.css">
    <script src="Carousel.js"></script>
    <title>Carousel</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>This is the Carousel</h1>

    <div id="carousel">
        <div class="carousel_item carousel_item--visible"><img src="Images/Sasuke.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
        <div class="carousel_item"><img src="Images/Spider-man.jpg"></div>
        <div class="carousel_item"><img src="Images/The Dark Knight.jpg" ></div>
        <div class="carousel_item"><img src="Images/Arcane.jpg"></div>

        <div class="carousel_actions">
            <button id="carousel_button--prev"> < </button>
            <button id="carousel_button--next"> > </button>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```

and my
JS:

```
let curr_pos = 0;
const slide = document.getElementsByClassName('carousel_item');
console.log(slide.length);
```

In this as you can see I have 4 items with .carousel_item so the console should display 4, however it is showing **0**.But if I use console.log(slide.length) in Browser console then it shows **4**.

Now either I have to start Js from scratch or the browser is gone mental.
Please someone help!

Answer (score 2):

HTML documents are parsed top to bottom. When a `script` tag is encountered, all other parsing stops until the script has finished execution.

Therefore, elements placed after the `script` tag will not be visible in the DOM to the script.

To solve this, move the `script` tag's position to the bottom of the `body` tag:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Carousel.css">
    <title>Carousel</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>This is the Carousel</h1>

    <div id="carousel">
        <div class="carousel_item carousel_item--visible"><img src="Images/Sasuke.jpg" alt="" srcset=""></div>
        <div class="carousel_item"><img src="Images/Spider-man.jpg"></div>
        <div class="carousel_item"><img src="Images/The Dark Knight.jpg" ></div>
        <div class="carousel_item"><img src="Images/Arcane.jpg"></div>

        <div class="carousel_actions">
            <button id="carousel_button--prev"> < </button>
            <button id="carousel_button--next"> > </button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="Carousel.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```